# Google Cloud Run - Run Shell Script in firebase project

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm new to google cloud-run and I'm hoping to achieve to run scripts in the firebase project to update configs (env variables)

here's the process

firebase function invoked-> pass param(bar, baz) into cloud run -> run scripts `firebase functions:config:set foo.bar=baz`

What I have done is to crate an image of firebase-tools shared by cloud-builders-community, and below is the code

```
// cloudbuild.yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase', '.']
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
tags: ['cloud-builders-community']
```

and below is the Dockerfile

```
//Dockerfile

FROM node

RUN npm i -g firebase-tools
ADD firebase.bash /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/firebase.bash

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/firebase.bash" ]
```

so from here, I was wondering how to write and run scripts.
Any idea or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Run allows you to host containers that answer to HTTP request.

In your design, how did you manage to invoke your container? ... Yes you don't have any endpoint defined.

I contributed on an open source project and I discovered a tool that serve you automatically bash script as http endpoint. Have a look to this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/alpine-firestore-backup/blob/master/Dockerfile). It use the tool [shell2http](https://github.com/msoap/shell2http)

In your case, I recommend you to have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM node
RUN npm i -g firebase-tools
ADD my_script.sh /
COPY --from=msoap/shell2http /app/shell2http /shell2http

RUN chmod +x my_script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/shell2http","-export-all-vars"]
CMD ["/update","/my_script.sh"]
```

Write your `my_script.sh` to run the bash command that you want according with the query params.

Example of working `my_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
firebase --version
```

And, after building your container and deploying it on Cloud Run, invoke `https://myservice.....run.app/update?<your env var>`

**EDIT**

For the Firebase authentication, you have 2 solutions, but before going in detail, you have to generate your refresh token as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems)

1. Use the env var to pass your token. It's not the most secure because your token is in plain text into the Cloud Run env var.

Deploy your service like this

```
gcloud run deploy --image=... --set-env-vars=TOKEN=<tokenValue>
```

And build your `my_script.sh` file like this

```
#!/bin/sh
firebase --token $TOKEN <command>
```

2. Use [secret manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs). It's more secure but require more thing to do. Start by saving your firebase refresh token into secret manager

```
echo "<tokenContent>" | gcloud beta secrets create --replication-policy=automatic --data-file=- myFirebaseToken
```

I changed the way to create the container because I need to use gcloud. Thus here the new container

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm
RUN echo $(npm i -g  firebase-tools)
RUN node -v

ADD my_script.sh /
COPY --from=msoap/shell2http /app/shell2http /shell2http
RUN chmod +x my_script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/shell2http","-export-all-vars"]
CMD ["/update","/my_script.sh"]
```

2 remarks:

- The default node version is 12. I don't know if it's an issue for you
- The node 12 version is an issue for firebase tools because there is 1 dependency deprecated. And the `npm i` command exit with a non zero code (and the build failed). The hack here is to surround the command with an echo `RUN echo $(npm i -g  firebase-tools)`. Not really clean, but it works.

And now the `my_script.sh` file

```
#!/bin/sh
TOKEN=$(gcloud beta secrets versions access --secret=<mySecretToken> latest)
firebase --token $TOKEN <command>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I appreciate it. So I tired without any param but hardcode variables and below is the code 
``` 
#!/bin/sh
firebase functions:config:set hello.world=test123 
```

and I invoke https://myservice.....run.app/update
but got the err msg ```exec error: exit status 1``` and my Dockerfile is the same as the above that you suggested

maybe I should look more into Docker but any idea about this? maybe entry point is not right?

Comment: I edited my answer. After tests, I missed to make executable the my_script.sh file. Look at my new dockerfile, I directly use the Node image. It's an example, not mandatory. In an case, it prints the firebase version.

Comment: Thank you. it actually works when logging firebase tools version. but other firebase commands like firebase functions:config:set or firebase deploy that requires auth, it did not work.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to this topic and providing solution. I've tried the above,(option 1), using refresh token and save it as env var as suggested. but still getting these ```exec error: exit status 1``` I think my shell script is out of syntax but have no clue what is wrong.
```firebase --token $TOKEN use test-123 && firebase --token $TOKEN functions:config:set foo.bar=baz```
Also I tried without using ```&&``` but did not work, either. If you could advise what needs to be fixed in my_script.sh, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Did the container build in success? Is the service well deployed? Where do you see this error trace?

Comment: yes. it was built and deployed successfully. ```firebase --token $TOKEN --version``` or ```firebase --token $TOKEN projects:list``` command works in my_script.sh. it prints out the info on the browser. but when I modified my_script.sh with different commands like ```firebase --token $TOKEN functions:config:set foo.bar=faz``` or ```firebase --token $TOKEN use test123``` it did not work but throw the ```exec error: exit status 1``` error

Comment: Did you tries the command locally? With the same token? Maybe you can have more details!

Comment: yes I did try locally with the same commands which worked fine. can't figure out why it gives me the error when running the commands ```firebase --token $TOKEN functions:config:set foo.bar=faz``` or ```firebase --token $TOKEN use test123``` which worked w/o any errors locally

Comment: Sadly, it's out of my scope. I haven't any firebase project and I can test this part on my side...

Comment: Thank you for your support and help. I appreciate it