# Run firebase cli on Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, google-cloud-run

**What I want to acheieve**
So using Cloud Run, I wanted to achieve as below

1. Firebase Cloud Function(FCF) invoked
2. FCF makes a call to the other API service and fetch a certain value `{bar:baz}`
3. FCF makes a call to Cloud Run endpoint with the value as params
4. Cloud Run that was built and deployed with Docker Image of Firebase CLI gets triggered
5. in Cloud Run, it executes the commands `firebase functions:config:set foo.bar=baz`
6. Successfully updates FCF environment variables as `foo.bar=baz`

**Issues**

so previously asked here, [Google Cloud Run - Run Shell Script in firebase project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62462157/11015504) and with the solutions that were provided by @guillaume blaquiere, I finally got to the point where I run commands like `firebase --version` or `firebase projects:list` and they worked fine as the information is printed out on the browser.

However, when I run the commands like `firebase use project test123` or `firebase functions:config:set foo.bar=baz`, Cloud Run throws the error `exec error: exit status 1`

**Source Code**

```
# Dockerfile

FROM node
RUN npm i -g firebase-tools

ADD my_script.sh /
COPY --from=msoap/shell2http /app/shell2http /shell2http

RUN chmod +x my_script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/shell2http","-export-all-vars"]
CMD ["/update","/my_script.sh"]
```

```
#my_script.sh

#!/bin/sh
firebase --token $TOKEN use foobarbaz-123
firebase functions:config:set foo.bar=baz
```

when build image with gcb

`gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/foobarbaz-123/testbash`

when deploy

`gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/foobarbaz-123/testbash --platform managed`

or deploy with token that I get from `firebase login:ci`

`gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/foobarbaz-123/testbash --platform managed --set-env-vars=TOKEN=foobarbaz12345`

where do I need to fix? Any advices or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: @doug-stevenson, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen, maybe?